# Is there a thing as a void namespace in c++?

Tags: c++

I am currently learning C++ in UE4 or shall I say UE4 C++. I am trying to look at the C++ source code of my project, yet I see something like this `void AMyActor::BeginPlay()`. I am thinking `AMyActor` is a namespace but I don´t understand why there is `void` in front of it.

Comment: Is `void` the return type of the function?

Comment: You really need to [get a book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) that explains how `C++` works and study that first.

Comment: `AMyActor` is most likely a class and `void AMyActor::BeginPlay()` is most likely a function.

Comment: This is like trying to learn how to be come a civil engineer solely by studying the blueprints for the Eiffel Tower. It is necessary to first learn the core fundamentals of C++ by following an organized, methodical, study curriculum in a quality C++ textbook before diving in and trying to understand how an extremely complicated, large C++ code base work, and how it does what it does.

Comment: UE4 uses "classic"  as opposed to "Modern"  C++. Getting good with basic C++ is not a lot of study. By that I mean chapters 1 to 7 on "C++ Primer"  that @Galik recommended.  https://www.amazon.com/Primer-5th-Stanley-B-Lippman/dp/0321714113

Comment: *"I am thinking `AMyActor` is a namespace"* -- the name `AMyActor` suggests that it is defined by your project, which would mean that you should *know* -- not merely think -- what `AMyActor` is. Knowing what your identifiers represent is an important step towards knowing why they are used. This brings up another question -- do you know what `BeginPlay` is?

Answer (score 2):

> I see something like this `void AMyActor::BeginPlay()`. I am thinking AMyActor is a namespace but I don´t understand why there is void in front of it.

`void` is a keyword. It is a special type. It cannot be the name of a namespace.

`void AMyActor::BeginPlay()` is a function declaration. `void` is the return type of the function.